# I integrated maven in eclipse . then i imported a existing maven project using import wizard. i got the following error please help me out

Tags: eclipse, maven, alfresco, pom.xml, m2e

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.alfresco.maven:alfresco-sdk-parent:1.1.1: Failure to transfer org.alfresco.maven:alfresco-lifecycle-aggregator:pom:1.1.1 from https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of alfresco-public has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.alfresco.maven:alfresco-lifecycle-aggregator:pom:1.1.1 from/to alfresco-public (https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public): No response received after 60000here
```

error point first line of the code which is
File Name **Pom.xml**
I am using **Eclipse Kepler**

```
   //Eclipse shows error in first line

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fosspro</groupId>
    <artifactId>fosspro_aid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fosspro_aid AMP project</name>
    <packaging>amp</packaging>
    <description>Manages the lifecycle of the fosspro_aid AMP (Alfresco Module Package)</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </parent>
```

Please Help me Out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add the repository in your pom (inside `project`)...

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>alfresco-public</id>
    <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
  <!-- You may not need the snapshots? -->
  <repository>
    <id>alfresco-public-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

...or if you prefer, in the `settings.xml` of your Maven configuration.

I assume that the issue is as follow: the repository address is defined in the pom of the SDK, but in order to access the pom of the SDK, Eclipse needs to know the address of the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Maven fails to access https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/, so it's not an issue with your setup it seems that there are issues connecting to Alfresco's Nexus to fetch the dependencies.

It seems unresponsive for me at this very minute, try again in a few minutes.